# Weights and Bias set to NaN

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I am performing linear regression on one of UCI Machine learning repository data set. Below is the code :-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

wine_data = pd.read_csv('data/winequality-red.csv', delimiter=';')
n_samples = wine_data.shape[0]

train_x = wine_data.iloc[:, :11].values
train_y = wine_data.iloc[:, 11].values

training_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.03
n_input = 11
n_classes = 1
display_step = 10

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, n_input], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)

# Weights and Biases.
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_classes]))
b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn())

# Construct Linear Model.
prediction = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(prediction - Y, 2))/(2 * n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(1, training_epochs + 1):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X: train_x,
                                         Y: train_y})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            cost, x, y = sess.run([loss, W, b], feed_dict = {X: train_x,
                                                             Y: train_y})
            print (x)
            print (y)
            print ('Step ' + str(step) + ', Minibatch Loss = ' + \
                   '{:.4f}'.format(cost))
    print ('Training Done!!!')
```

Now, weights and biases get set to Nan only after single step.

```
[[14430.979  ]
 [  918.5443 ]
 [  484.25635]
 [ 4654.437  ]
 [  151.41441]
 [31196.336  ]
 [97207.76   ]
 [ 1732.7361 ]
 [ 5743.218  ]
 [ 1149.8185 ]
 [18074.775  ]]
1735.9697
Step 1, Minibatch Loss = 32277641302114304.0000
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
nan
Step 10, Minibatch Loss = nan
```

What all reasons could result weight and biases carry Nan?

Comment: Normalise the input and check what happens? basically when you have high input values it leads to more oscillations

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some NaN values in your data set.

First time it is printing the random values which are generated for the weights.  But after first step, that means, after the first update of weights, they are becoming NaN. That means there is some NaN values or some missing data in the training data.

Check your training data. I am not clear how tensorflow handles the NaN or missing data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should change

```
train_y = wine_data.iloc[:, 11].values
```

into

```
train_y = wine_data.iloc[:, :11].values
```

similar to the variable `train_x`.

Next to that, with your current implimentation you use the same training data in every iteration. You probably want to change `train_x` and `train_y` within the for loop.